# Connection issues with Mongo replica sets

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

Having a strange issue whereby I've set the mongodb uri to be.

```
mongodb://User:Password@machine1.uk.com:27017,machine2.uk.com:27017,machine3.ukx.com:27017/test_db_name
```

However when I use the following spring configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

<mongo:mongo />

<mongo:db-factory uri="${datamanager.host}" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>

<mongo:repositories base-package="com.datasource.service" />

<task:annotation-driven />
```

I get the following exception. Note the fact that machine1 has had its extension "uk.com" removed.

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches {serverSelectors=[ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}, LatencyMinimizingServerSelector{acceptableLatencyDifference=15 ms}]}. Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches {serverSelectors=[ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}, LatencyMinimizingServerSelector{acceptableLatencyDifference=15 ms}]}. Client view of cluster state is {type=ReplicaSet, servers=[{address=machine1:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: machine1}}, {address=machine2.uk.com:27017, type=ReplicaSetSecondary, averageLatency=11.7 ms, state=Connected}, {address=machine3.uk.com:27017, type=ReplicaSetSecondary, averageLatency=11.8 ms, state=Connected}]
```

For now I've updated my host file to change it to the IP Address which works but it seems strange.

Comment: Just to say I debugged the code and the full path is being added at the time it creates the INetAddress within the Mongo code.

Comment: Which Spring Data MongoDB version do you use? The usage is correct. Your problem _might_ be related to DNS configuration/a lookup issue.

Comment: I'm using 

Spring Data Commons 1.9.2-RELEASE
Spring Data Mongo 1.6.2-RELEASE
Mongo driver 2.12.5

These look a little old so I'll have a look at upgrading these.